# Display Core Data in UITableView Sections

Tags: ios, uitableview, sections

I have an NSMutableArray contacts, which I get from CoreData and I want to display this data in a UITableView with Sections, based on an attribute in the data model.

*For Example:*

Datamodel with the attributes name (String), section(Integer 16):

1. testuser1, 1
2. testuser2, 0
3. testuser3, 0
4. testuser4, 1

UITableView: ([Image-Example](http://www.bilder-upload.eu/upload/c7884b-1408963398.png))

Section 0:
Cell 0: testuser2
Cell 1: testuser3

Section 1:
Cell 0: testuser1
Cell 1: testuser4

My questions are:
1. How can I count the rows for each sections?
   I know I have to use the way below but how can I count how much contacts have a 0 or 1 in section?
2. How can I display them now in the right section?

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        if (section == 0) {
            return rowsSection0;
        } else {
            return rowsSection1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: is there any type in CoreData to split user types in section? say for example: users:[{name:testuser1, type:premium},{name:testuser2, type:basic}]

Comment: yes the section-attribute:
users: [{name: testuser1, type/section: 0}, {name: testuser2, type/section: 1}]

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone -- breaking up Core Data into sections with NSFetchResultsController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8382116/iphone-breaking-up-core-data-into-sections-with-nsfetchresultscontroller)

Answer (score 0):

Best way to display Core Data records in UITableView is to use NSFetchedResultsController.
You can find a tutorial to use NSFetchedResultsController [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller).

In your NSFetchedResultsController init method provide sectionNameKeyPath parameter value the name of the field according to which you want to create the section. In your case "section".

Also don't forget to set the NSSortDescriptor accordingly.

I also suggest you Google a little before putting a question here. This question has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8382116/iphone-breaking-up-core-data-into-sections-with-nsfetchresultscontroller) as well.

Comment: I am already using NSFetchedResultsController, also tried it with NSSortDescriptor, but nothing worked until now.
The sectionNameKeyPath is new for me, will look that up, thank you!

And i am working now 2 days at this problem, already searched a lot in google and also on stackoverflow but nothing helped, else i would ask the question.

Comment: Good @AdityaMathur, however this still isn't an answer. You could flag and mark the post as duplicate, and put your link as a comment. Answers providing links to tutorials, with little information, are not considered as answers.

Comment: @Neeku I do realise that just providing a link to the tutorial is not to be considered as an answer. But the way initially the question was asked I thought that providing a link to tutorial would be the best way for Mannism to understand Core Data and NSFetchedResultsController as it will provide him/her a better understanding. I could have serve the ready made code but that will not help him/her.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *contacts = []; //your Data array;
NSMutableArray *section0Contacts = [NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *section1Contacts = [NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for(NSDictionary *dict in contacts)
{
     if([[dict valueForKey:@"type"] isEqualToString:@"section1"])
         [section0Contacts addObject:dict];
     else if([[dict valueForKey:@"type"] isEqualToString:@"section2"])
         [section1Contacts addObject:dict];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(section ==0)
       return [section0Contacts count];
    else if(section ==0)
       return [section1Contacts count];
    else
       return 0;
}

/**
 *  RETURNS TITLES OF SECTIONS IN UITableView
 */
-(NSString *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
    if (section==0) return NSLocalizedString("Section 1", nil);
    else if (section==1) return NSLocalizedString("Section 2", nil);
    else return @"";
 }
/**
 *  RETURNS VIEW OF SECTIONS IN UITableView
 */
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
    UILabel *sectionTitle = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    sectionTitle.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 10);
    sectionTitle.text = [self tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:section];
    sectionTitle.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Your font name" size:12];
    sectionTitle.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 350.0f, 30.0f)];
   [headerView setBackgroundColor:[constants filterSectionBgColor]];
   [headerView addSubview:sectionTitle];
   return headerView;
 }
/**
 *  RETURNS HEIGHT OF SECTIONS IN UITableView
 */
 -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
   {
     return 30.0f;
   }
```